# Targeting one row, not all that has a certain value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a basic adding system, that allows landlords to add tenants, and tenants then have the ability to accept/reject. Accepting is very simple, when the tenant clicks accept, the accept boolean changes to 1. At the moment this is changeing all rows to accepted, not just the one between the landlord and tenant.

This is an example row in the database:

[image: Row]

If a tenant clicks accept, the accepted row will change to 1, and request sent will revert to 0. The users are now connected.

However, all rows that have `accepted = 0`, and `request = 1`, will be affected, not just the current row.

This is the accepted controller

```php
public function accept(Request $request)
{
    Tenancy::where('accepted', 0)
        ->where('request_sent', 1)
        ->where('tenant_id', Auth::id())
        ->update([
            'accepted' => 1,
            'request_sent' => 0,
        ]);

    return back();
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

Route URL

```
Route::post('/account/tenancy/{id}/accept', 'AccountController@accept')->middleware('auth');
```

Entire form and logic for accept/reject

```
 @if($currentUser->userType == "Tenant")
                @if($tenancy == null ||$tenancy->accepted == 0 && $tenancy->request_sent == 1 && $tenancy->tenant_id == $currentUser->id)

                    <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/accept">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept Request">
                    </form>
                    <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/reject">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Reject Request">
                    </form>
@endif
```

[dd($tenancy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRQN9.png)

Comment: You could pass the id of the row to the http request and just `Tenancy::find($request->get('id'))`, or is that impractical in your applocation?

Comment: That sounds like it could work tbh.

Comment: Let us know in here if it works or you have further questions :)

Comment: The ID should be the row id right? How would I get that actually? The view has an accept button with the rollowing url <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/accept">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept Request">
                    </form>

Comment: The form looks good, could you also share the route for it?

Comment: I'm going the edit the question, so the code is more readable

Comment: could you share the rest of the form as well? i'd like to know if a `$tenancy` variable exists in it, if so : `<form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$tenancy>id}}/accept"> {{ csrf_field() }} <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept Request"> </form> `

Comment: I will do it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments/recent edits, i believe this should work:

Change all

`action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/accept"`

to

`action="/account/tenancy/{{$tenancy->id}}/accept"`

and your `accept/reject` methods in the controller like this:

```
public function accept(Request $request, string $id)
{
    Tenancy::find($id)
        ->update([
            'accepted' => 1,
            'request_sent' => 0,
        ]);

    return back();
}
```

Comment: Isn't `$user->id` just the users id instead of the tenancy id?

Comment: @Paul oh yes, i looked over that, i'll edit my answer 

Answer (score 0):

You are missing another where. You are just filtering for the two statuses and the tenant_id, but you want to filter by the landlord_id aswell.

Something like `Tenancy::where('accepted', 0)->where('request_sent', 1)->where('tenant_id', Auth::id())->where('landlord_id', $id);`.

However, what happens, if there are two tenancies between a landlord and a tenant? You probably want to pass the tenancy id in the request and retrieve the tenancy in your accept function by the id. Important thing to keep in mind here is to make sure, that the [current user is allowed](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization) to accept the tenancy with the id he passed.

**Edit** based on your new code in the question:

This would be the approach of my recommendation, not the additional landlord_id.

```
<form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$tenancy->id}}/accept">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept Request">
</form>

public function accept(Request $request, $id)
{
    Tenancy::find($id)
        ->update([
            'accepted' => 1,
            'request_sent' => 0,
        ]);

    return back();
}
```

You should still keep in mind, that an authorization/check would be needed.

Comment: How would I pass the landlord ID into the following view <form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/accept">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Accept Request">
                    </form>

Comment: We would need a bit more code to help you. Do you have a tenancy object you want to accept in the view? If yes, an action of something like `/account/tenancy/{{$tenancy->id}}/accept` would be just fine combined with my suggestion/the code of @Quezler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50198786/targeting-one-row-not-all-that-has-a-certain-value/50198824?noredirect=1#comment87414262_50198786

Comment: I updated the question with the rest of the form, and a dd of $tenancy

Comment: @JackSmith12 i have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50198951/6056864) based on how your form looks

Comment: Thanks for the additional code, updated my answer too.

Comment: That works mostly. It updates the accepted attributed to 1, but doesn't revert the request_sent to 0

Comment: Strange, is `request_sent` [mass assignable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)? However, you should see an exception if it isn't. You could run `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` after executing the update to see what the query did.

Comment: It wasn't in the fillable array, for whatever reason. I assumed it was. Working fine now. Thank you